# ARM assembly, getting error compiling on very first line

Tags: assembly, arm

```
.text
.globl main
main:
```

```
Error: unexpected character `t' in type specifier
project.s:1: Error: bad instruction `ï»¿.text'
```

what could be causing this?

Comment: What specific assembler are using, and what is the exact command you are invoking it with?  Have you looked at the assembler's manual to confirm that `.text` is a valid thing to write?  Have you tried re-typing your assembly code from scratch with your keyboard to make sure there are no weird characters in the tile?  Are you able to compile a simple example program from someone else?

Comment: Is that a UTF-16 BOM (byte order mark)?  Looks like you have some non-ASCII bytes in your file that your editor is hiding from you.

Comment: It's actually [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Byte_order_marks_by_encoding). I guess the assembler simply doesn't like the BOM itself, there don't need to be any strange characters.

Comment: Peter Cordes- i think that must be it, how could i get rid of these bytes

Comment: With an editor that doesn't magically hide them from you.  e.g. VIM or emacs.  Or a hex editor could change them to something else.  Or copy/paste your text into a new plain text file using an editor that doesn't insert this non-ASCII stuff at the start of text files.

Comment: I will try this thanks